# Google cloud ubuntu virtual server - tweepy rate limit exceeded no matter what

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, tweepy

So I have a python program that searches for tweets, which works absolutely fine on my pc, this query isn't about the code, but about the actual bash console. However when I run it on my virtual server (I have installed all dependencies, modules and python versions needed), I get the error:

```
  File "allcode.py", line 194, in <module>
    everything('#twitter-tag')
  File "allcode.py", line 56, in everything
    user = api.me()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 354, in me
    return self.get_user(screen_name=self.auth.get_username())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/auth.py", line 140, in get_username
    user = api.verify_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 599, in verify_credentials
    return bind_api(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 231, in execute
    raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.RateLimitError: [{'message': 'Rate limit exceeded', 'code': 88}]\
```

I can run the exact same code at the exact same time on my own PC without issue, so the rate limit has obviously not been exceeded. Could it be something to do with the requests the server sends out?

Comment: Make sure your developing and deployment environment may be the same (same python version, same dependency versions). Your script may have errored out earlier and spammed API requests. After getting a rate limit error you should wait for some time before trying again else you will continue getting rate limit error. If all those steps still failed someone else may be spamming the API and the ban was applied to a range of ip addresses which you happen to fell into.